# Could "giving aids" be ambiguous?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, homonyms

In Wiktionary the noun  *[aid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aid)* is defined as

> **aid** (plural ***aids***)

1. Help; assistance; succor, relief.  
   *He came to my aid when I was foundering.*
2. A helper; an assistant.
3. Something which helps; a material source of help.  
   *Slimming aids include dietary supplements and appetite suppressants.*

---

And then there is *[AIDS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AIDS)* which is

> Acquired immune deficiency syndrome.

---

I'm not a native speaker, and I may fail to understand a part of the context, so I need to have a clue from somewhere else.

**When hearing: *"Do you have/want aids?"* How can I tell what this person is talking about?**

I am not asking about *formal* context, but *oral* and *possibly joking*.

---

**EDIT :** I removed the *government help* part since comments are saying that is a mass noun and so, uncountable.

---

**EDIT 2** : Some are arguing that *"aid"* in its meaning of help is not used in plural form. I searched on [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and find 3 examples of *"aids"* usage on the 200 first results.

I excluded the *"{sense} aids"* as in @MarkDriver answer to only keep basic usage and not special medical tool.

> 1. Several risk management frameworks and tools have recently become available that will be valuable **aids** in preservation and curation work.

> 2. I don't see any of those " Per Rialto " or " Per San Marco " signs, my navigational **aids**, on the sides of buildings.

> 3. On the fourth hour of " The Today Show, " Hoda and Kathie Lee had a conversation about marital **aids**.

Comment: The word *aid* is a mass noun. Even before the syndrome *AIDS* was named, it was rarely (if ever?) pluralized; now, it never is. If you hear someone ask you "*Do you want aids?*", that person is either a non-native speaker or setting up a very grim joke. You should never ask "*Do you want aids*" or "*Do you have aids*" yourself. Only use *aid* (singular / mass) for the sense of assistance.

Comment: Nobody offers others "Do you want AIDS?". Also, this disease mostly called HIV. e.g. **An interview with an HIV-infected person**.

Comment: @DanBron How do you call money that a government gives to a person in need?

Comment: That assistance is called "*government aid*" (a mass noun). It is never pluralized to "*government aids*". And @Eilia HIV is the disease (pathogen), AIDS is the ultimate condition.

Comment: @YohannV You can insist all you like. The reality is he same: *aid* is a mass noun, and in the sense of "rendering assistance" simply is not pluralized. We don't say "assistances", we don't say "helps" (as a plural noun) and we don't say "aids" (as a plural noun). These are all mass nouns and used as mass nouns. If you're interested in the fundamentals of mass nouns vs count nouns, as opposed to the word *aid*, specifically, you might get more helpful answers on [ELL.se], who have a lot of experience explaining the concepts to non-native speakers of English.

Comment: As a UK native speaker I endorse entirely what @Dan Bron has said. *Aid* is a mass noun and is not pluralised. A.I.D.S. is an entirely different thing. The only legitimate use of *aids*, meaning assistance, would be as the third person of the verb *to aid* - *she aids the distressed*.

Comment: @DanBron & WS2 I understand what mass nouns are since they exist in my natural language. I am just confused about *"aid"* being one. Do you have any source of this?

Comment: @YohannV People who want to provide detailed write-ups offering authoritative sources do so in answers; comments are used for guidance. If you want to know whether *aid* is used as a mass noun, refer to a reputable dictionary. If you want to compare many dictionaries at once, onelook.com is a good resource.

Comment: As @Dan has mentioned incidentally, saying “AIDS […] AKA HIV” is factually incorrect. HIV is **not** the same as AIDS.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Removed this part which was not my point anyway.

Comment: @YohannV Good! Remember that OneLook itself is not a dictionary, but links through to many dictionaries. It would be a good idea, and improve your experience on EL&U, if you chose one or two reputable dictionaries as your "favorites" and got familiar with their layouts, notation, conventions, etc, and referred to them before asking questions of meaning, gloss, etymology, etc (and hen mention what you found in them in the bodies of your questions themselves). OneLook is a good way to "window shop" around to choose your favorite dictionaries.

Comment: @DanBron Before posting I refered to wiktionary and macmillandictionary which is partly based on thesaurus and I though it was not enought clear to ask. (I still don't find clear infos that other usages are rare)

Comment: @YohannV For serious purposes, you may discard Wiktionary from your toolkit. Its content and reliability are *not* on par with Wikipedia's. And yes, some dictionaries suit our individual tastes and mental models better than others, which is why I pointed out OneLook as a way to "shop around" for one that does work for you. But ultimately, using the dictionary or any other tool effectively is a matter of practice. It's easier for native speakers, of course, because we already "know" the answer, no only refer to the dictionary to get an explanation or research subtleties and nuances.

Comment: @DanBron wiktionary is not bad for etymology. But ok, I will now take it with much more care.

Comment: Why is this not just moved to ELL ?

Comment: @JoeBlow I don't ask about meaning, grammar or rules but about *"aid"* usage.

Comment: @DanBron you should assemble your first three comments and make that the answer, I for one, would upvote it. I had never thought that the question *"Do you want aids?"* could be misinterpreted as a request for assistance. It is, of course, a sarcastic, bitter and ultimately stupid stock phrase, used nowadays in place of "Do you want a black eye?" or "Do you want to blow me?"

Comment: I think the main trouble with this post, which I think is a legitimate question, is in its title. If you write "Is giving aid a good thing?" the unanimous response will be: "Yes, of course!"  But writing "Is giving AIDS a good thing?" is like asking "Is it good if I give cancer to a child?" It's really quite an insulting and nonsensical question, and until you read the post and realize that the OP is genuinely (well, I hope he is) confused. It does sound like a provocation. I would change the title, or say something like: **Could "giving aids" be ambiguous?**

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think I want to provide a formal answer: for one thing, I think the title of the question is baiting and I don't want to encourage such questions on touchy or borderline offensive topics. You're right that a title change would go a long way to softening that. But more importantly, I tend to comment on but not answer questions which have trivial answers (from a native speaker's perspective) on their face, or rest on obviously (again, from a native speaker's perspective) faulty premises. Such questions should be encouraged on ELL, but not here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, good idea. I've VtC the question here, and raised a custom flag for the mods to consider migrating to ELL.

Comment: If the only point is to make me edit the title, I will do it.

Comment: @YohannV. No, that's not the point.  We're simply discussing whether this question would be better placed on ELL.  We (the user community) have no ability to move it ourselves, so ultimately it'll be a moderator's call.

Comment: The fact that aid has a plural form does not imply that it is a count noun in all of its senses.  Many mass nouns have secondary senses in which they are countable.  "Beer" comes to mind.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I added some "aids" examples found on http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/ . What do you think about them?

Comment: @YohannV. I love that you're digging deep into this question here and doing so much research, and getting familiar with so many tools of the trade! But note that all of the examples in your latest edit are  *physical objects*, not instances of "*helps*". Note also that they're *all qualified with adjectives* (*visual*, *navigational*, *marital*, etc).  In other words, these are things of things Mark Driver was getting at in his answer (though he failed to elaborate or support it!).

Comment: Good edits. It is still unclear to me the context. Are you saying this sentence to someone else and you want to know how to say it better? Or are they saying it to you and you want to understand what they mean? In the first instance we can suggest alternatives and what they mean exactly. In the second, the sentence is given and can't be changed, and we would have to interpret the intention. Which is it?

Comment: @DanBron Only the second one is physical object. (First is service and second is rights and money) The fact that they are used with qualified adjectives enforces the possibility of confusion when talking, ie when context may be the main indicator of this adjective we are talking about.

Comment: @Mitch I am answering for possible future conversation with people if I reach the door of my cave

Comment: @YohannV. No, the 2nd and 3rd are definitely physical objects. Google "*marital aids*" if you don't believe me (but perhaps it would be best to do it in a private tab; they're definitely *not* rights and money). Number one is abstract, but it's still a *tool* (it even says so expressly), not the *act of rendering assistance*. The fact that they're always qualified with adjectives is a hint that *aids*, plural, is almost never used *without qualification*, so the basic premise of this question "*is 'giving aids' ambiguous?*" is moot, because *no one ever says that* (except to mean AIDS).

Comment: Yohann, so do you want to know how to ask a question about aids, or if people come to you asking something about 'aids'? (the latter will be much more speculative)

Comment: @DanBron I googled it >< I though about money between separated parents, my bad. But if the context is about those tools, is the adjective needed?

Comment: @Mitch I am trying to figure out a possible conversation when the context may allow me to chose about my interlocutor is talking

Comment: @YohannV. Yes, the adjective is needed, because the phrase "marital aids" is a fixed euphemism: you could not elide *martial* without confusing people. Seriously, I'm not trying to be contrary or contentious here; I'm telling you, as a native speaker (pathetically, a monolingual native speaker) that no one uses bare *aids* in a way that ever create ambiguity with AIDS. If they do so, either they're being *intentionally obscure* in order to set up a joke (ie the usage is deliberately jocular), or they're a non-native speaker who isn't aware *aid* is a mass noun. That's as plain as I can put it.

Comment: @YohannV. Turn that question to Mitch around; try to construct a conversation where you *wouldn't* be able to immediately understand what specifically your interlocutor was talking about, from context. Hint: you won't be able to (or, if you do, it'll be hard, and also probably very contrived, as the jokes other people have posted demonstrate).

Comment: Yohann, so you're saying you _want_ to be ambiguous in this imagined conversation where you use the word 'aids'?

Comment: @Mitch No **I** don't but I imagine my interlocutor would.

Comment: @DanBron Ok, I understand your point and now I don't know what to do about this question. I still want to try to make a conversation setting the ambiguity (you shouldn't have said I can't) but if I fail, what should I do?

Comment: @YohannV. If you want to construct a context where *aids* is ambiguous, then that's what you should ask in your question (though if that's the case I don't understand why you just told Mitch that's *not* what you're looking for). If you've framed the question in its current form because you believe "help me write a joke" would be closed as POB or off-topic, that's disingenuous and an abuse of the spirit of the site's rules. Don't do that. Ask what you want to ask and let the question stand or fall on its own merits. And of course *anything* is "doable" in English; but can it be done *well*?

Comment: Yohann, this is still unclear. Who is speaking the word 'aids' first, you or the other person?

Comment: @Mitch I imagine that doesn't matter?

Comment: @DanBron I don't want to do a joke. But I was imagining a situation where *"aids"* is ambiguous for me when hearing someone else use it without adjective. I cannot post it for the moment.

Comment: @YohannV. In real-life, native-speaker conversations, that situation will never occur. That ambiguity ("*multiple instances of the act of assisting*" vs "*Acquired Immune Deficiency Syndrome*") will never occur. If you're worried about it, don't be. If you're asking about it for some other reason, please describe that reason, in detail, in the body of your question. If you're satisfied knowing that "*aids*" == "*multiple instances of the act of assisting*" does not exist nor occur in the English language, you may consider voting to close this question, or deleting, since it has no +1 answers.

Comment: No native speaker will say 'Do you want aids?' when 'Do you need help?' is intended (they'll use the latter). In the most formal tone, they might say 'Do you need aid?' (singular). If someone says 'Do you want aids?' It would only be understood to mean 'Do you want the HIV associated disease called AIDS?'. Along with everything else people have said, this is the most direct response to your OP only after a lot of explanation of the situation.

Comment: I will simply close this question since Dan say this will never occur. I thank everyone which has took time to read me and comment.

Comment: Hum I can't, so I will wait for something, a good answer or I will answer myself.

Comment: @YohannV. You should be able to either close-vote or delete your own question (EDIT: oh, I see someone has +1'd one of the answers; that will prevent you from deleting it). But if you can add a substantive, correct, and well-sourced self-answer, that would be even better. But please don't add an answer which claims "*aids*" can be used as a plural meaning "*multiple individual acts of rendering assistance*", because as we discussed, that's not true.

Comment: @DanBron Are you kidding? You are explaining since 40 hours that *"aids"* can't be used like that. I won't say this usage is correct ... **even with a knife on my throat !**

Comment: @DanBron if you post an answer, just glue together the different comments, I will add the missing fifth vote. A win-win situation! ??

Comment: @Mari-LouA Wait, aren't you now curious to see Yohann's self-answer? I sure am! I want t to see what he's taken away from this whole dialog, but even more keenly I want to know what his motivation was in the first place!

Comment: There are far far too many comments, I limited myself to reading the last three. A mod will come, sooner or later and delete the lot. I'd advise Yohann to delete the ones that are clearly obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First

My question was not as good as I thought when it came in my mind so I am posting a proper answer based on comments (principally of @DanBron and @Mari-LouA)

---

#### The mistake

Three major meanings steered me to post this question :

- AIDS, Acquired immune deficiency syndrome,
- aid, mass noun synonym of help,
- aids qualified with adjectives (medical, navigational, etc)

---

### Why those meanings are not ambiguous :

- **AIDS**, someone wishing you this is not worth rub shoulders with or is a terrible joker
- > **aid** is a mass noun, and in the sense of "rendering assistance" simply is not pluralized. We don't say "assistances", we don't say "helps" (as a plural noun) and we don't say "aids" (as a plural noun). ([Dan's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252865/could-giving-aids-be-ambiguous#comment-551706))
- **aids** in its plural refers to objects and is always preceded by an adjectives to indicate what is the purpose of the tool (visual, hearing, ...).

And to conclude another [Dan's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252865/could-giving-aids-be-ambiguous#comment-552485) :

> That ambiguity ("multiple instances of the act of assisting" vs "Acquired Immune Deficiency Syndrome") **will never occur**.

---

#### From where the mistake came

My question is coming from online gaming. It is a team game, where you don't often know your mates. There is multiple roles which are *complementary* and you have to play well alone *and* with your team to succeed to beat the enemy team.
People are not always nice and insults are coming very fast when you are starting to fail. Moreover, it is an international game in which natives are not the majority and english is not often correct.

After, have done a mistake, I was asked if I wanted aids. I refused politely because I was not sure about what it was and came here to ask.

Comment: Oh, woo! I thought you'd had forgotten about us and were never going to post your final answer. +1. But you know what I would really, really like? If you could include a summary of your actual, real-life *original motivation* (with as much detail as you're willing to share!) for asking this question in the first place. I'd personally find that really interesting, but more importantly I think it would help other people coming to English from another language, in the future.

Comment: @DanBron I'll never forget you ! ;) I'll edit my answer in a couple of hours to add this situation.

Comment: Aha! Now it all makes sense! Such a sense of resolution! Thank you.

Comment: +1 a bit late in the day, I had almost given up hope of seeing an answer. Interesting history, I see why you were confused when someone posted "Do want aids?". What a horrible, and ignorant person.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you're asking what is meant when someone says "Do you have aids?" or "Do you want aids?" in the context of spoken English, and possibly humour.

There are only two possible interpretations (owing to the aides/AIDS homonym):

1. "Do you have/want AIDS?"

   - They are asking about the syndrome resulting from HIV
2. "Do you have/want aides?"

   - They are asking about your assistants (people)

Anything else would grammatically incorrect and also not-colloquial enough to make a joke out of. This is because "aids" as you use in your question can not stand on its own in "Do you want aids?" It would have to be "Do you want aid?" (as in assistance, which is help-- not to be confused with "aides", as in assistants, who are people)

---

Edit: I spent some time considering marital aids (things that help in the bedroom such as sex toys, ED medications, etc) and came up with the following dialogue...

> Jack: So me and the Mrs. got some new marital aids; it has really spiced things up.
>
> Henry: Oh yeah? What sort of... *wink* aids?
>
> Jack: I'd rather not go into details...
>
> Henry: Right, probably for the best.

It's grammatically correct... and it makes sense. However using "aids" in this sense is VERY context specific and only works because of the previous dialogue. You would never use the word "aids" without having mentioned what kind previously, for context. Which is why if someone said something that sounded like "Do you have aids?" the meaning would almost never be ambiguous *except* for the AIDS/aides issue mentioned earlier.

---

Incoming bad joke:

> Steve is the Director of Human Resources at BigCorp. George is his long time friend who works in a different department. They are out for drinks after work...
>
> Steve: So the new VP wants me to give him aides.
>
> George: I know it's not the death sentence it was 30 years ago, but what a strange request. (Makes the expression: ;D)
>
> Steve: Haha, you know what I mean.

Comment: As you can see in my second edit examples, if the context is about *"marital aids"* for example, the person could think that talking about *"aids"* without a precising adjective will be understand.

Comment: Hopefully my edit responds to your comment adequately, let me know if anything is still unclear. Keep in mind, of course, that someone could deliberately misinterpret "aids" for the sake of a joke.

Comment: @YohannV. When you're talking about *marital aids*, the context is such that it would be dangerous to the point of irresponsible to talk about "*giving [your partner] aids*". For that reason,  in this context, shortening *marital aids* to something like "*devices*", or more commonly and less clinically "*toys*" is much more idiomatic. Alternatively, one could talk about specific devices and use words like "*dildos*", etc.

Comment: @DanBron I totally misundertood what marital aids are.

Comment: @Yohann Which is why you are both right AND wrong. It is grammatically correct AND ambiguous to say "aids" in that context. Which is why you never actually would. This is why we have more words with more explicit definitions. Homonyms are a thing in English, and it's important that the definition you intend is the obvious one in the context. Just to reiterate: context context context! :)

Comment: @mfoy_ You are right, but context is a subjective thing ^^'

Comment: @Yohann Which is why you need to make an effort to be clear and *not* ambiguous when speaking. :p

Comment: @mfoy_ About your answer, I was not thinking about assistant nor dildo but about an help. I need time to set a good conversation example to point out the confusion about *"aids"*

Comment: @Yohann does my crappy joke work? lol

Answer (score 1):

The phonetic similarity between *AIDS* and *aids* or *aides* is sometimes used for dark comedic effect, either intentionally (as in the *South Park* episode “Jared has Aides”) or unintentionally (as in 1970s [Ayds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UP_uiiRAZqs) commercials).

Comment: My feeling is this should be a comment, rather than an answer.